# CSS Visited Link Error

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, visited

I have CSS made by me. I used it to make my nav link in green color. So I used `a:visited`. Then mouse over visited link won't make work `hover` properties. Please help me to make it green and red when hover. [sorry for my bad English]

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
}
#nav a:link {
    color:green;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:visited {
    color:green;
}
#nav li:hover {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:21px;
}
#nav li {
    float:right;
    margin: 5px;
}
#nav li#active {
    font-family:arial;
    font-color:red;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav li#active:active {
    font-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Just put the `#nav a:hover` rule **after** the `#nav a:visited` rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn about [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

`#nav a:hover` and `#nav a:visited` are *equally [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)* so the [last one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) will override the first one.

Put the `:hover` rule after the `:visited` rule if you want it to overwrite the other way around.